# How to connect Firebase in Chart.js?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, chart.js, ionic3

I'm using Ionic and I have a CRUD that creates a list of name "Item":

**item.models.ts**:

```
export interface Item {
    key?: string;
    data: string;
    humor: string;
    mania: string;
    numero: string;
    medicamento?: string;
    dormidas?: string;
    menstrual?: boolean;
    evento?: string;
    impacto?: number;
    outras?:  string;

}
```

See how the data is stored in firebase:

[image: Tree]

So, how to connect the list data created in my chart done in Chart.js?
I can create a static graph only, I would like the graphic to be dynamic and with the data stored in Firebase. On the X axis I want to put the variable "data" and on the Y axis the variable "numero".

**.HTML CODE:**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div style="display: block;">
  <canvas baseChart width="600" height="400"
              [datasets]="lineChartData"
              [labels]="lineChartLabels"
              [options]="lineChartOptions"
              [colors]="lineChartColors"
              [legend]="lineChartLegend"
              [chartType]="lineChartType">
  </canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

**.TS CODE:**

```
 import { Item } from '../../models/item/item.models';

  public lineChartData:Array<any> = [
  {data: [-34, -78, 45, 65], label: 'Humor'}
  ];

  public lineChartLabels:Array<any> = ['19/jun', '20/jun', '21/jun', '22/jun' ];

public lineChartColors:Array<any> = [
  { // grey
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.2)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
    pointBorderColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
  }
];
public lineChartLegend:boolean = true;
public lineChartType:string = 'line';
```

[image: Chart]

Could someone please help me connect Firebase to my chart?
I have not found any material on the subject.
If possible, I would like to see a practical example.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic 3 is based off Angular 2/4/5.
There is a library that you can use to connect to Firebase called `AngularFire2`.

Here's the documentation:
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2

As far as the chart is concerned, you can get the data retrieved from the firebase. (Usually you have to loop through the array of retrieved Firebase data and clear the `lineChartData[0].data` element and assign the retrieved data into the element. Afterwards, two-way binding in Angular will do its magic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your suggestion is the traditional model, however it doesn't work to connect the firebase and graph. I already tried to do this, but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you show the code to assign the data to the graph?